# Limit of $4GMmdx/(d^2-x^2)^2$ as $x\to 0$

Tags: limits

I am looking at a physics problem but struggling to understand the limit of the problem.

So $d$ is the distance between two particles and $x $ is a point between the two particles.
Total force acting on the particle at $x$ is $F=4GMmdx/(d^2-x^2)^2$ where $G$ is the gravitational constant and $M,m$ are the mass of the two particles. Now the problem claims that as $x\to 0$, the limit of $F$ is equal to $\frac{4GMm}{d^3} x$ since the quantity $x^2$ can be neglected in comparison to $d^2$. But the numerator tends to $0$ as $x\to 0$. So why is the limit not $0$?

Comment: The limit is $0$; the asymptotic behaviour, which you might see called limiting behaviour, is $4\pi GMx/d^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us set $F(x) := 4 G M m \frac{x d}{(d^2 - x^2)^2}$ as well as $F_0(x) := 4 G M m \frac{x}{d^3}$ for $x > 0$.
The limit of $F$ for $x \to 0$ can't have any $x$ terms in it, since we took a limit with respect to $x$. (In fact, $\lim_{x \searrow 0} F(x) = 0$.)

Your textbook probably means that in the limit $x \to 0$ (that is, **asymptotically**) **$F$ behaves like $F_0$**, that is
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{F(x)}{F_0(x)}
= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{x}{d^3}}{\frac{x d}{(d^2 - x^2)^2}}
= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{d^3} \frac{(d^2 - x^2)^2}{x d}
= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(d^2 - x^2)^2}{d^4}
= 1.
$$

---

Another topic is how $d$ and $x$ are related. I am not sure how $x$ (probably a real positive number) represents a particle, but my intuition would be that if $x$ is a particle in between two other ones $x_1, x_2$ and their distance $d$ goes to zero, then $x_1 = x = x_2$.

Comment: Or more simply the denominator has a limit $d^4$ while the numerator has limit $0$ so it should be $0$ by the limit rule?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician Excuse me, you are correct. The limit is 0.